# TensorFlow throws std::system_error on calling tf.Session()

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda

I have a virtual environment set up using anaconda on a remote server. The environment is based on Python3.7 and has TensorFlow installed using pip. The python interpreter returns a system error on calling the TensorFlow function Session().

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session()
```

This produces the following error:

```
2019-05-08 16:56:05.239001: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help on figuring out the reason for this behavior would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue in case if I try to run the second tensorflow app on the same machine